# Why is the equality operator on object returning false?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to manipulate the view of a web messaging system and the default view is a blank object, `{}`. I used an `ng-show="data.currentView == {}"` in my AngularJS script to check if it is currently the default view, but it never showed. Then I tried this in my Javascript Console in Chrome:

```
var data = {}
console.log(data == {})
//Logs false
console.log(data === {})
//Logs false
```

Why is that statement returning false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing to see if two objects are *the same object*, not if they are *identical* objects.

See [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3):

> If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then … Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing references with objects, so they are never equal. A good way would be:

```
Object.keys(data.currentView).length == 0
```